# Error Call to undefined method Doctrine\DBAL\Connection::createSchemaManager()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10, infyom

Im installing laravelgenerator https://infyom.com/open-source/laravelgenerator/docs/10.0/installation

and I want to use the "Generate From Table" https://infyom.com/open-source/laravelgenerator/docs/generator-options#custom-table-name

```
php artisan infyom:scaffold Post --fromTable --table=posts --connection=remote
```

my DB
[image]

and my code in console with the error
php artisan infyom:scaffold Qrcode --fromTable --table=qrcodes

```
   Error 

  Call to undefined method Doctrine\DBAL\Connection::createSchemaManager()

    1228▕     }
    1229▕
    1230▕     /**
    1231▕      * Get the Doctrine DBAL database connection instance.

  1   vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager.php:469
      Illuminate\Database\Connection::getDoctrineSchemaManager()

  2   vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php:353
      Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager::__call("getDoctrineSchemaManager", [])
```

I did the dependency update, check database configuration, and the infyOm configuration, the qrcodes Tablen but nothing is wrong.

any idea please?

Comment: This looks like this is probably not your fault. Have you searched the issue tracker of that project if other users already summoned the same error message, perhaps even in an identical use-case?

Comment: @hakre I have searched but the problem or a similar one does not appear.

Comment: I'd perhaps consider to report it then, because if you followed the docs and they use Doctrine as a dependency, there might be a problem / gap with how that library defines their requirements. As this needs investigation with the developers they should at least know about it, right? Wouldn't writing a good report in their tracker not be helpful? Not saying you should remove the question here, but you can link vice-versa (cross link) so you also keep nice hypertext references, nowadays preferred way of documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solution is update the doctrine in composer.json

in this case `"doctrine/dbal": "^3.5",`